# Technical difference between format and quick format in windows platform?

Tags: windows, operating-system, command

i have many times seen this on my system that when i format my 16GB pen drive using **just right click on it and then select format**, then it takes **a lot of time to format**, but when i select **quick format** then it takes **very less time**. Can anyone please tell what is the **technical difference** between these two process?

Comment: any one who wants to close this question, kindly specify your comments....

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but I suspect that the reason for down/close votes is that typing "windows quick format" into Google's search field results in a search suggestion for "windows quick format vs long format", which in turn will give you the MSDN page with the answer to your question _as the very first hit_.

Comment: @Michael, sometimes experience OR knowledge of users tell more accurate things that other web-sites. hence i preferred to post this question here....

Comment: Certainly. I'd say that MSDN is a pretty reputable site, though. And in the end the answer you got (and accepted) came directly from the very same page that I mentioned in my previous comment, which only goes to show that a search engine should be your first resort - then ask here if you find no / unclear / conflicting information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you choose to run a regular format on a volume, files are removed from the volume that you are formatting and the hard disk is scanned for bad sectors. The scan for bad sectors is responsible for the majority of the time that it takes to format a volume.

If you choose the Quick format option, format removes files from the partition, but does not scan the disk for bad sectors. Only use this option if your hard disk has been previously formatted and you are sure that your hard disk is not damaged.

If you installed Windows XP on a partition that was formatted by using the Quick format option, you can also check your disk by using the chkdsk /r command after the installation of Windows XP is completed.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686

Answer (score 4):

Full - set up zeroes in every cell, quick - change file system headers only.